# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this proc in my PL/SQL.
when i run it in sql dev, it is giving me exactly one row (one column)

```
PROCEDURE Newpo_code(sp_code OUT VARCHAR2) 
IS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT To_char(Max(num)) 
    INTO   sp_code 
    FROM   (SELECT "ordernumber" num 
            FROM   "purchaseorder" 
            WHERE  ROWNUM = 1 
            ORDER  BY "pkpurchaseorderid" DESC) 
    WHERE  ROWNUM = 1; 

    SELECT Substr(sp_code, 10, 2) 
    INTO   sp_code 
    FROM   "purchaseorder"; 
END newpo_code;
```

but when i run it from code level

it is giving me exception

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

What am I missing here?

I searched this exception but found no helpful results.

Comment: Are you sure that the second query is not returning more than one row? It has no WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to go on, but most likely this is the line failing:

```
select substr(SP_CODE,10,2) into SP_CODE from "PurchaseOrder";
```

Why? Because there are probably more than 1 row in the `PurchaseOrder` table, which field you are trying to fit in one variable, `SP_CODE`.

You probably need a `where` clause on `PurchaseOrder`.

Answer (score 0):

```
PROCEDURE Newpo_code(sp_code OUT VARCHAR2) 
IS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT To_char(Max(num)) 
    INTO   sp_code 
    FROM   (SELECT "ordernumber" num 
            FROM   "purchaseorder" 
            WHERE  ROWNUM = 1 
            ORDER  BY "pkpurchaseorderid" DESC) 
    WHERE  ROWNUM = 1; 

    SELECT Substr(sp_code, 10, 2) 
    INTO   sp_code 
    FROM   dual; 
END newpo_code;
```

Done!
Thanks anyways.

Comment: Much better done using: `sp_code := Substr(sp_code, 10, 2);` instead of the unnecessary select from dual

Comment: The 'answer' using WHERE ROWNUM=1 will always update/use the first (or oldest) row, instead of the exact row you are looking for. Be VERY cautious when operating with such statements and be as exact as possible when doing this type of operations.